# Is $\{(x,y) \mid (\exists f\in \operatorname{Homeo}(X))(f(x)=y)\}$ closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $A$ be the set all $(x,y)\in X^2$ for which there's a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Is $A$ closed?

**EDIT:**
I think
$$A=\bigcup_{f\in \operatorname{Homeo}(X)}f$$

Comment: Your edit is correct.

Comment: So is it really a standard thing to denote the graph of a function $f$ by $f$? I

Comment: $f$  can be regarded as a relation on $X$, that is, a subset of $X^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X=[0,1]$ with the usual topology inherited from the absolute value.

For every $n\geq 2$, it is easy to construct a piecewise affine homeomorphism $f_n$ of $[0,1]$ onto itself such that
$$
f_n\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}.
$$
So the points $(1/2,1-1/n)$ belong to $A$ and they converge to $(1/2,1)$ in $[0,1]^2$. Now if there was a homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ onto itself such that $f(1/2)=1$, we would have
$$
[0,1]\setminus \{1/2\}=f^{-1}([0,1)).
$$
The lhs is disconnected, while the rhs is connected. Contradiction. So $(1/2,1)$ does not belong to $A$. Hence $A$ is not closed.

Comment: You can be slightly more precise (with the same ideas): $A$ is the interior of the square plus the four corners $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I only meant to answer the question and did not bother to determine $A$ completely. I guess I was lazy...

Comment: Hmmm. Posting a full answer versus posting a comment-hint. Who wins? :-)

Comment: @Martin You obviously win: you've got three upvotes with your comments.

Comment: I removed them, so you get the deserved votes. I'll stop bothering you with irrelevancies now, promised.

Comment: @Martin I don't recall you've ever bothered me.